# How can I share my full app (.yml file) with others?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created an app which consists of many components so I use docker-compose.
I published all my images into my private repository (but I also use public repos from other providers).
If I have many customers: how can they receive my full app?
I could send them my docker-compose.yml file per email or if I have access to the servers, I can scp the .yml file.
But is there another solution to provide my full app without scp'ing a yml file?

Edit:
So I just read about `docker-machine`. This looks good, and I already linked it with an Azure subscription.
Now what's the easiest way to deploy a new VM with my docker-application? Do I still have to scp my .yml file, ssh into this machine and start docker-compose? Or can I tell to use a specific .yml during VM creation and automatically run it?

Comment: Docker isn't meant at creating shrink wrapped applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official distribution system specifically for Compose files, but there are many options.

The easiest option would be to host the Compose file from a website. You could even use github or github pages.  Once you have it hosted by an http server you can `curl` it to download it.

There is also:

- [composehub](https://composehub.com/) a community project to act as a package manager for Compose files
- Some related issues: [#1597](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1597), [#3098](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/3098), [#1818](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1818)
- The experimental [DAB](https://docs.docker.com/compose/bundles/) feature in Docker

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it out but docker-compose isn't installed on the machine! Do I have to manually install it or is there some option to automatically install it at the `docker-machine create` command - I didn't find sth. like this.

Comment: Is it best practise at all what I'm doing? Or should I separately start all of my container instead of using compose?